# google type error when trying to assign an element of 2d array

Tags: javascript, multidimensional-array

I am having trouble on google adwords scripts, I keep getting "TypeError: Cannot read property '0' from undefined." Both allDates[1] and yearSpend are arrays with 365 elements

```
function populateBaseline(yearSpend) {
  var allDates = baselineRange();
  var range = allDates[1];

  var baselineData = new Array(365);
  for (var i=0; i<365; i++) {
    baselineData[i] = new Array(2);
  }

  for (var j=0; j<365; j++){
    baselineData[j][0] = range[j];
    baselineData[j][1] = yearSpend[j];
  }

  return baselineData;
}
```

Comment: You're probably getting that error on `baselineData[j][0]`, meaning `baselineData[j]` is `undefined`.

Comment: `baselineData` is not the problem. pleasè provide some information about `baselineRange();

Comment: I figured it out, there was a different problem in the main function unrelated to populateBaseline() entirely that resolved this issue, thanks for the help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're probably getting that error on `baselineData[j][0]`, meaning `baselineData[j]` is `undefined`.

You don't need to iterate over `baselineData` twice. Use this instead of your 2 `for` loops:

```
var baselineData = [];
for (var i = 0; i < 365; i++) {
    baselineData[i] = [range[i], yearSpend[i]];
}
```